# Changing text back on double click or unfocused state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown labeled 'View Capacities' which changes label to 'Hide Capacities' when clicked. 
I'm trying to get it to change back to original label when it's double clicked (when toggle closes) or when user clicks elsewhere in window.

HTML:

```js
//JQUERY:

$('.FullLengthDropdown').focus(function(){
  $('.ViewCapacitiesTxt').text("HIDE CAPACITIES");
});
```

```html
<button class="FullLengthDropdown btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle " type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <div>
    <span class="ViewCapacitiesTxt">VIEW CAPACITIES</span>
  </div>
</button>

<table class="dropdown-menu">
  <tr>
    <th>SPACE</th>
    <th>RECEPTION</th>
    <th>THEATRE</th>
    <th>BANQUETING</th>
    <th>CABARET</th>
    <th>BOARDROOM</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried to create jsfiddle but your code is not working

Comment: You say that you want this to be activated on a click event but you're activating on a focus event?

Comment: before postion, please check errors in your code (like <th"> and </table) thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add an focus out?!

```
$('.FullLengthDropdown').focusout(function(){
    $('.ViewCapacitiesTxt').text("VIEW CAPACITIES");
});
```

Comment: @RamishMian if you accepted this answer, make it 'accepted'

Answer (score 1):

Use `focusout`, `dblclick` and `toggle()` to achieve this.

```js
//JQUERY:

$('.FullLengthDropdown').on('focusout dblclick', function(){
  $('.ViewCapacitiesTxt span').toggle()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="FullLengthDropdown btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle " type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <div>
    <span class="ViewCapacitiesTxt">
      <span>VIEW CAPACITIES</span>
      <span style="display:none">HIDE CAPACITIES</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</button>

<table class="dropdown-menu">
  <tr>
    <th>SPACE</th>
    <th>RECEPTION</th>
    <th>THEATRE</th>
    <th>BANQUETING</th>
    <th>CABARET</th>
    <th>BOARDROOM</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below source. If you observe when you click on text below the button it will be toggle back to original text

```js
 function toggleText() {
                var toggleText = $('.ViewCapacitiesTxt').attr("data-toggle-text");
                $('.ViewCapacitiesTxt').attr("data-toggle-text", $('.ViewCapacitiesTxt').text());
                $('.ViewCapacitiesTxt').text(toggleText);
            }
            $('.FullLengthDropdown').click(function () {
                toggleText();
            });
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).click(function (e) {
                    if (!$(e.target).hasClass("FullLengthDropdown")) {
                        if ($('.ViewCapacitiesTxt').text() != $('.ViewCapacitiesTxt').attr("data-orginal-text")) {
                            toggleText();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <button class="FullLengthDropdown btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle " type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <div>
                <span data-toggle-text="HIDE CAPACITIES"
                      data-orginal-text="VIEW CAPACITIES"
                      class="ViewCapacitiesTxt">VIEW CAPACITIES</span>
            </div>
        </button>

        <table class="dropdown-menu">
            <tr>
                <th>SPACE</th>
                <th>RECEPTION</th>
                <th>THEATRE</th>
                <th>BANQUETING</th>
                <th>CABARET</th>
                <th>BOARDROOM</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
```